# Most secure SSH server

Tags: linux, ssh

Which SSH server (compatible with Debian Wheezy) has the fewest (if any) exploitable security bugs?

Comment: Usually when a so critical service as SSH is exploited, they usually hurry up fixing their problems so, unless you use an old fashioned and outdated ssh server, just go ahead taking one like openssh-server. After all they usually hurry up fixing the problems also (if any).

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I do not understand why this question has been marked as off-topic, as I'm not asking for a product recommendation, only asking which server has the fewest security issues (which I would think is on topic for a computer security site).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most secure server is the one which is most efficiently maintained. So this would point at the default SSH server (which happens to be [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/)): if a security flaw is found in that software, it can be expected that the corresponding patch will be made available within a few hours, and you will get it through the normal Debian update mechanisms (that I hope you dutifully apply on a daily basis).

**Theoretical framework:** you cannot know bugs which are not discovered yet, so the best that can be hoped for is to fix bugs as soon as they become known, and hope that actual attacks will strike somebody else. That's how 95% of software security works, and it works "fine" for now. The remaining 5% are proactive analysis and sane development practices which should prevent most bugs from coming to existence in the first place; OpenSSH has good reputation in that respect, and since it is so widely used, this implies some level of public scrutiny (some people are looking for bugs) and also a profusion of targets, thus making it much less probable that *you* are being hit before the patch becomes available.